# Django AJAX search function

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to make a search function in my Django project using AJAX. But the functions in views.py don't seem to work properly. And maybe I have some other mistakes. Could you please tell me what I need to correct?

This is my AJAX file:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$('#suggestion').keyup(function(){
    var query;
    query = $(this).val();
    $.get('/friends_plans/suggest_users/', {suggestion: query},   function(data){
        $('#user').html(data);
    });
});
});
```

This is part of my template:

```
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-list">
   <li class="nav-header">Find user</li>
   <form>
      <li><input class="search-query span10" type="text" name="suggestion" value=" " id="suggestion" /></li>
   </form>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="user">
</div>
```

These ara functions from views.py:

```
def suggest_users(request):
users_list = []
starts_with = ''
if request.method == 'GET':
    starts_with = request.GET['suggestion']
users_list = get_users_list(5, starts_with)
return render(request, 'friends_plans/list.html', {'users_list': users_list})

def get_users_list(max_results=0, starts_with=''):
users_list = []
if starts_with:
    users_list = Person.objects.filter(username__istartswith=starts_with)
if max_results > 0:
    if len(users_list) > 0:
        users_list = users_list[:max_results]
return users_list
```

This is from urls.py:

```
url(r'^suggest_users/$', views.suggest_users, name='suggest_users')
```

The `istartswith` method doesn't work properly with the variable but does with the constant, I can't understand why. And `suggest_users` function doesn't return `users_list` to the object with id `user` (`$('#user').html(data)`), nothing appears on the page. But maybe there are some other mistakes.

Comment: looks like you are posting data on a get, not sure why you are doing that.  Check the browser console, it will return the error being sent back by the server assuming you're in debug mode.  I would start there.  If you post data you need to pass the csrf-token which is used to prevent cross site forgery.  There is documentation about that on Django's site.

Comment: Chris, the OP is sending data with a get request which is perfectly normal. The url will end up being something like `http://foo.com/resource?foo=bar`

Comment: This is not valid python code. If you are seriously interested in getting help and learning, please follow the minimum rules regarding indentation.

Answer (score 2):

Django's `render` function renders HTML after parsing it with Jinja. If you want to write a view that acts as an endpoint for an AJAX function, you do not want that view to return `render`.

Instead you should use return `JsonResponse`. `JsonResponse` accepts a dictionary as an argument. And it builds a proper JSON object for you. :) Which will then be picked up by your AJAX's success function.

Here's an example of how to use `JsonResponse`:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def some_endpoint(request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = dict()
    data["foo"] = "bar"
    data["username"] = User.objects.get(id=request["id"]).username
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

This will cause your view to return a `JSON Object`, which is what your AJAX function is looking for.

Second suggestion I would make would be to use jQuery's `$.ajax()` function rather than jQuery's shortcut `.get()` function. The advantage of this would be learning all the parameters that go along with AJAX calls.

Here's an example of jQuery's `$.ajax()` function.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#suggestion').keyup(function(){
        var query = $(this).val();
        $.ajax(function(){
            type: "GET",
            url: "/friends_plans/suggest_users/",
            data: {suggestion: query},
            success: function(data){
                console.log("SUCCESS");
                console.log(data);
            },
            failure: function(data){
                console.log("FAIL");
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```